# Output Webpage (Variable URL) with Database values, using PHP Template

Tags: php, mysql, templates, design-patterns

*I did some searching around, but I'm not very experienced in PHP, so I don't know the correct Terms/Words I am looking for.
However, I do have a good idea of what I want to do.*

1. I have a website with many images, each image has a database entry (MySQL).
2. I would like each image to have its own landing page, based on its database values. (`Title`, `Category`, `Tags`, etc...)
3. I don't want to make a separate .php file on my server for each image. (Eg: `pinkflowers.php`, `redroses.php`, etc...)
4. There should be 1 PHP template file, that outputs the webpage for ALL images, based on the URL (variable) that the user visits.

So if someone visits "mysite.com/pinkflowers.php", the page should be output with the variables of `pinkflowers` from my database.

However, the file `pinkflowers.php` doesn't actually exist, only `template.php` exists, which would be the "blueprint" for all the images in my database.

1. I would like the `.php` to be removed from the URL in the browser.

   "mysite.com/pinkflowers.php" => "mysite.com/pinkflowers"

   I already have code that does this with my existing pages *(below)*; I'm not sure if it will also work with these "imaginary" pages.

   ```
   (.htaccess)    
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
   ```
2. If the user tries to visit a page that has no related database entry (eg: "mysite.com/430jfif0ij"), they should be re-directed to the homepage.

*I'm not expecting anyone to give me ALL the answers, but please at least guide me in the right direction to begin making such a template.
Thanks!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve my own question eventually, in the mean time that no Answers were given.

I followed this Tutorial here:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/

My `.htaccess` contained:

```
RewriteEngine on    
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^category1/(.*)$ ./template.php?image=$1
RewriteRule ^category2/(.*)$ ./template.php?image=$1
RewriteRule ^category3/(.*)$ ./template.php?image=$1
etc...
```

`category#` - being the "folders" that my images are categorized by.

I did this on the `template.php` to extract the Variable from the URL:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM image_list WHERE image_name="' . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['image']) . '"');
```

To `redirect` the visitor to the Homepage if they enter an invalid URL/ID, I used this:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0) {
echo "<script>window.location = 'http://mysite.com/'</script>";
}
```

So the combination of all these methods achieved exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Let your .htaccess be something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ template.php/$1
```

Then (on `template.php`) use `$_SERVER["path_info"]` to determine the path the user has entered (i.e. `/pinkflowers`) and query the database accordingly.

The reason I like `$_SERVER["path_info"]` is because it doesn't use (or pollute) the GET variable space.

Comment: Thanks!
I was eventually able to solve it on my own after long sarching, when I stumbled across this Tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/

Your method looks quite close to mines. I'd rate it UP if I could.

I did try your `$_SERVER["path_info"]` suggestion, but it wasn't working out for me somehow. I'm still a noob at this.
`$_GET['image']` worked out fine for my purposes.

Thanks again!